# Magento 2 : Get ordered products in sales_order_after observer

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, sales-order

Is their any way i can get the product names in `sales_order_place_after` observer ?

I get the order object but not sure how to fetch the products.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the product names like this:

```php
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
$order = $observer->getOrder();

foreach ($order->getItems() as $item) {
    // retrieve the names from the order items
    $productNames[] = $item->getName();

    // or retrieve the names from the product instance
    $productNames2[] = $item->getProduct()->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get product names from order object like as follows:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $arrProductNames[] = $item->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the ordered product order data from the *sales_order_after* observer in the order that you would like, parse the orders in an orderly manner:

```
$fantasticOrderData = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

foreach ($fantasticOrderData->getAllItems() as $evenMoreFantasticItemData) {
    $superDuperCoolProductNames[] = $evenMoreFantasticItemData->getName();
}
```

I trust this answer is in order.